# Given a set $A \subseteq R$,$i \in Z$ ,$A_i=A+i$, $\bigcup_i A_i=R$,{$A_i$} pairwise disjoint, is $A$ necessary an interval?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Given a set $A \subseteq R$,$i \in Z$ ,$A_i=A+i$, $\bigcup_i A_i=R$,{$A_i$} pairwise disjoint, is $A$ necessary an interval?

$A+i$ means set $A$ has all it's elements translated by an amount $i$.

The result  is obviously true if $A$ is an interval for example $A=(0,1]$. But is it always the case?

Comment: I think, it should be $A\subset\mathbb R$ and $i\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @MundronSchmidt 10x 4 d correction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $A=(0,1)\cup \{2\}$. Then you can see
$
A_i\cap A_j = \emptyset
$
for $i\neq j$ and $\bigcup_i A_i=\mathbb R$.

But you can do it more extreme. For example, you can divide $[0,1)$ in countable subintervals and shift each by different integers.

In addition, you can choose a nowhere connected set. But that is a little bit more technical.

Comment: please could you answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2632997/given-a-set-a-subseteq-r-n-in-n-q-in-q-a-n-anq-bigcup-n-a-n-r

Comment: Try it yourself first. Otherwise, you won't learn how to do such a task.

Comment: alright, Thanks

Comment: Looks like $ A=(0, q)  \bigcup $ {$ 2q $} will do for the other question, anyway i edited the other question.