# Given a set $A_q \subseteq R$,$n \in Z$ ,$q \in Q$ ,$A_n=A_q+nq$, $\bigcup_n A_n=R$,{$A_n$} pairwise disjoint , is $A_q$ a measurable set??

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Given a set $A_q \subseteq R$,$n \in Z$ ,$q \in Q$ ,$A_n=A_q+nq$, $\bigcup_n A_n=R$,{$A_n$} pairwise disjoint for a given $q$.

$A_q+nq$ means set $A_q$ has all it's elements translated by an amount $n*q$.

is  $A_{q}$ necessary a measurable set?

It is not difficult to see if $ R$ is replaced with open interval $(a, b) $ then $ A_q $ must be of the form $ A_q = I \bigcup S $ where $ I $ is a countable union of intervals and $ S $ is a countable set.

Comment: You should try it yourself. I gave you an idea how to tackle such a problem in your other question.

Comment: "The result is obviously true if Aq is an interval"  What result is obviously true is $A_q$ is an interval?  That $A_q$ is an interval?  Yes, If $A_q$ is an interval we can conclude $A_q$ is an interval? And if $A_q$ is not, it isn't.

Comment: @fleablood it means union of $ A_n $  is the entire $ R $

Comment: I believe it is not always measurable

Comment: I have to point out, that if the index set for $n$ is $\mathbb{N}$, then it's impossible to satisfy $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n=\mathbb{R}$ and $\{A_n\}$ pairwise disjoint simutanously.To see this, assume $\{A_n\}$ pairwise disjoint. Choose $x\in A_1=A_q+q$, then we see that $x\notin A_n,\forall n=2,3,\dots$. Now I claim that the number $x-q$ is not in any of the $A_n$. Assume otherwise, say $x-q\in A_k$ for some index $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Then we see that $$x\in A_k+q=A_{k+1},$$with $k+1>1$, this shows that $x\in A_1\cap A_{k+1}$ and violates the fact that $\{A_n\}$ are pairwise disjoint.

Comment: @FrankLu thanks for pointing my error it should be $ n \in  Z $ rather than $ n \in N $